# Cloudformation Assistance with Elastic Beanstalk and Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Has anyone got links to installing an elastic beanstalk instance using cloudformation that uses an Application Load Balancer?
Examples I have seen all use a Classic load balancer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sets ASG size and Application Load Balancer.

```
Resources:    

  MyConfingTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties: 
      ApplicationName: !Ref ApplicationName
      OptionSettings: 

        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: EC2KeyName
          #ResourceName: String
          Value: !Ref EC2KeyName
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: InstanceType
          Value: t2.micro
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          Value: !Ref InstanceProfile      
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
          OptionName: MinSize
          Value: 3      
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
          OptionName: MaxSize
          Value: 6    
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
          OptionName: LoadBalancerType
          Value: application             

      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.0 running Python 3.7
```

List of other variables, such as for health checks, is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html).